# SVG dashed line animation

Tags: jquery, svg

I get svg line animation from codepen. it have 3 line animation. two dashed line animation and one solid line animation. I want the solid line animation with stroke. I tried to make the stroke solid to dashed, but not getting the animation. Dashed line animation is visible, but the solid line animation is visible the stroke on the move of the circle.

```
"http://codepen.io/mattsince87/pen/snqLy"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard "simulate the drawing of a line" animation is a trick that uses dash patterns to work.  Thus you can't use it for drawing an already dashed line.

About the best you can do, as a workaround, is cover the dashed line with a solid line the same colour as the background. Then animate the "undrawing" of the solid line on top to reveal the dashed line below.